# Reading tab delimeted files in c++

Tags: c++, file, parsing, delimiter, string-parsing

I am doing a project and could really use some assistance. I have stored my variables into a file, as is shown below, but separated them with tabs. Now i want to read them back out, as individual variables, so the question is, how do i read them without the tabs? Will i have to parse the string?

```
void fileManagement::appendCustomeRFile(const Customer &obj)
{
  if(tryFile(CFile))
  {
    ifstream cfile(CFile);
    cfile<<obj.ReturnCustomerId()<<"\t"<<obj.ReturnFName()<<"\t"<<obj.ReturnLName()<<"\t"<<obj.ReturnContactNumber()<<"\t"<<obj.RetrunBalance()<<"\n\r";
    cfile.close;
  }
}
```

This is how I am currently reading from the file.

```
void viewCustomerInfo(string contact_N)//
{
 tryFile(CFile);
 bool found=false;
 string retreivedId,retreivedFname, retreivedLname, retreivedNumber;
 double retreivedBalance;
 ofstream cfile(CFile);
 if(cfile.is_open())
  {
    while(!cfile.eof())
    {
        cfile>>retreivedId>>retreivedFname>>retreivedLname>>retreivedNumber>>retreivedBalance;
        if (retreivedNumber==contact_N)
        {
            found=true;
            cout<<"_______________________________________CUSTOMER INFO_______________________________________\n"<<"Customer ID: "<<retreivedId<<"\nFirst Name: "<<retreivedFname<<"\nLast Name: "<<retreivedLname<<"\n";
            cout<<"Contact Number: "<<retreivedNumber<<"\nCustomer Balance"<<retreivedBalance<<endl;
            cout<<"___________________________________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
            break;
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend using a tokeniser, either write one yourself or google for one (e.g.: boost includes one)

Comment: Don't use `eof`. Using `eof` is always wrong.

Comment: use a library from the boost project, boost tokenizer, http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/tokenizing-a-string-td2564907.html

Comment: I would use `std::getline(cfile, retreivedFname, '\t');`. It will get everything up to (but not including) the tab, but it will extract the tab from the input.

Comment: Please, pretty please, search StackOverflow before posting.  There are too many questions about comma separated values (CSV) or tab separated files.  You can get more examples by searching for "c++ read text columns from file".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I did however, most of them gave a different take on it, and I found it difficult to understand. So I thought asking directly and getting a reply would be easier for me to understand. Though I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing

```
while(!cfile.eof())
```

Try this instead

```
 while(cfile>>retreivedId>>retreivedFname>>retreivedLname>>retreivedNumber>>retreivedBalance)
```